# Directive's controller name match controller name?

Tags: angularjs

In this example (http://plnkr.co/edit/MDhqlsS8CXmmpQr5hkYN?p=preview).

1. In `function test()`, why not use `controller: 'testCtrl'`?
2. I think `controller: testCtrl` is the name of Controller? But when I change to `controller: testCtrl2` and `.controller('testCtrl2', testCtrl)`, it cannot work.

Comment: testCtrl is the variable referring to the function named testCtrl. If you use testCtrl2, since there is no such defined variable/function, then the controller is undefined.

Comment: I got. Where can you find that Controller: Name, this Name is function name instead of Controller name?

Comment: Most of the documentation actually says that the controller field expects a controller function, not a controller name, but both are accepted: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Please show all relevant code in the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site to review your issue. Demos are great, but should only be used to support what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: @JBNizet, in the document you provided, I did not see that controller function and controller name are both accept, can you highlight where they mention?

Comment: I couldn't find it either. I just know it's accepted.